# PushBots Registering Device with Alias

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushbots

While registering the Device with Pushbots i am not able to send the alias value to the server. The logs show it is sending the alias but when I check the list of the devices it does not show the alias value registered.

I am using this after initializing the Pushbots

```
Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);

Pushbots.sharedInstance().setAlias("john");
```

Is there any way to debug to know what data is being sent to register the device with Pushbots?

Logs:

```
05-10 14:55:47.785: I/PB2(673): PUT Request : https://api.pushbots.com/alias

05-10 14:55:47.786: I/PB2(673): Body builder msg original ; {"token":"","platform":"1","alias":"john"}




05-10 14:55:48.241: I/PB2(673): PUT Request : https://api.pushbots.com/register


05-10 14:55:48.241: I/PB2(673): Body builder msg original ; {"token":"APA91bFD1F6tYSTklUYTPRUQQQDSbmfTjMZK4jTxFxBCZtshH4IpPCakBUpN-JycSdPVj2sTJfYsKNcYpkwptvWo4Zn0H7MjM3MfJXO_Y7RCkqOPh3uxRzTZQSxUgKpJ72benHZJvYZ4","udid":"545422864f376713","tz":"Asia/Calcutta","platform":"1","carrier":"Vodafone IN","osVersion":"5.0.2","device":"XT1033","resolution":"1184x720","locale":"en_US","lib":"2.0.13","locale":"en_US","country":"in"}
```

Comment: Sir, did you find the solution ? Even I am having the same problem.

Comment: @VarunSharma no was not able to do it. their support team sux

Answer (score 0):

The `setAlias` functionality should be linked to a certain activity the user performs, it doesn't make much sense to give one marker for all users.

The reason this is not working is that you use the method directly after the initialization which takes time to register the device. So in essence, if your app has a login activity for example,  The setAlias method should be invoked AFTER a successful login from your user, not in the main activity.